spyder-notebook not opening ipynb files after installation with conda
I have installed spyder and spyder-notebook with conda on my Mac as per:
conda install spyder -c conda-forge
conda install spyder-notebook -c conda-forge

After restarting Spyder, I can see the "Notebook" pane next to the "Editor" pane as expected, and I can create a new notebook and it runs fine. However, whenever I try to open any existing notebook (as per the instructions in the main documentation here), an error always pops up:
File Load Error for <>.ipynb: file or directory '<>' does not exist
After dismissing the error, it prompts me to save my work and then closes the file. No existing .ipynb file can be opened. I have tried removing and reinstalling spyder and spyder-notebook (I tried with conda install conda-forge::spyder-notebook as well), and updating both packages.
The packages I've added explicitly in my current environment are: python (3.11.6), pandas, jupyterlab, spyder (5.5.4), spyder-notebook (0.5.1).

UPDATE: It turns out that Spyder is not opening .ipynb files located inside my OneDrive. I found that I cannot open ipynb files which are located in my OneDrive folder, although I can open ipynb files that are located outside of onedrive on my local computer. How do I give spyder-notebook access to my OneDrive folder? Note that the issue is only with opening ipynb files as notebooks through spyder-notebook. Spyder opens regular .py scripts properly whether or not they are inside my OneDrive folder. How can I give it permission for this?

Spyder does have OneDrive permission in Settings > Privacy & Security > Spyder > OneDrive. But the issue seems to be with spyder-notebook and I don't know how to give it OneDrive permission. spyder-notebook does not appear in my settings.

